# How do you run a Yii command from within your Module?

Tags: yii, yii-modules

Is it possible to have my module's custom commands show up in the list of application commands when you run yiic?

```
cd {yii_protected_folder}
yiic shell {full_path_to_my_yii_protected_folder}/config/console.php
```

I've tried adding the command into the commandMap array in console.php, but the command never shows up as an option in yiic.

```
'commandMap'=>array(
  'passwordtest'=>array(
    'class'=>'application.modules.myModule.commands.shell.passwordtestCommand',
),
```

The only way I can make it show up in yiic is to copy the passwordtestCommand.php file to {yii_protected_folder}/commands/shell/, but I'd rather keep the file within my module and reference it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not that hard, the `CConsoleApplication`-class has a getter for the `CConsoleCommandRunner`. This in its turn has an "`addCommands()`"-function that allows you to add paths. Just open up your `protected/yiic.php` and change it by this:

```
<?php

defined('STDIN') or define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/yii.php');

$app = Yii::createConsoleApplication(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php');
$app->commandRunner->addCommands('extraCommandPath');
$app->commandRunner->addCommands('extraCommandPath2');
$app->run();
```

After that you no longer require the `yiic.php` from the framework.

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a way by updating the console.php config file?  It seems odd that I'd have to update the yiic.php for each and every module's commands...

Comment: You don't have to update it for every command, it scans the folders you give it and finds all commands automatically. So you'd only have to update it if you add commands to another folder. And FYI, it's YOUR yiic.php that you have to update (in protected/), not the frameworks'

Comment: Hmm, I get Class 'Yii' not found on line 7

Comment: You have something like Yii::createConsoleApplication()->run() in there normally no? It needs to go just above that.

Comment: No, this is what my yiic.php file in the protected directory looks like: `<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/yiic.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php';

require_once($yiic);`

Comment: ah my apologies, I did this for one of my projects a long time ago.You'll have to include Yii yourself before doing the rest, let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
'commandMap'=>array(
  'passwordtest'=>array(
    'class'=>'application.modules.myModule.commands.shell.passwordtestCommand',
),
```

this help me with run module command in Yii 1.x

just add it into config/console.php or your different console config file.
also change the path part ".myModule.commands.shell.passwordtestCommand"

cheer, it's working for me.